# what's wrong with my code for insert sql?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, insert

I have these codes and it says syntax error in insert into statement.

```
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    String tempo = dateFormat.format(date);
    Global.temp1 = ""+Global.grandTotal;

 Global.s.executeUpdate(" INSERT INTO salesRecord(date,total,representative)" +
                        " VALUES('"+ tempo +"'," +
                                "'"+ Global.temp1 +"'," +
                                "'"+ Global.username.getText() +"')");
```

Global.temp1 is a string that gets the total value of items and converts it to string. can you help me with this?

Comment: Good lord. Use prepared statements.

Comment: Not using `PreparedStatement`, `static` references, trying to format the `Date` when it should be represented within the database as a `Date` (or `TimeStamp`)...

Comment: Have you tried to System.out your statement? Most likely the values of the vars you are using contains some characters that is making your insert invalid. Besides the lack of preparedStatement of course.

Comment: You've already been encouraged to use prepared statements. For further information look for the keywords *SQL injection* in the search engine of your choice. This should be general practice even when you don't rely on user input data for now.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bad way of use inset query. It is better to use `PreparedStatement`

You can try this.

```
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    try{
      conn=DriverManager.getConnection("");// get connection
      preparedStatement=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO"+ 
                                        "alesRecord(date,total,representative)" +
                                         " VALUES(?,?,?)");
      preparedStatement.setString(1,tempo);
      preparedStatement.setString(2,Global.temp1);
      preparedStatement.setString(3,Global.username.getText());
      preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    }catch(Exception e){
      //log the exception 
    }finally{
     //close the resources. 
    }
```

In your code there are issues with `'`